# In Ubuntu 17.04, for what this file is for /etc/modprobe.d/i915_disable_rc6.conf

Tags: keyboard, modprobe

I have found this file i915_disable_rc6.conf in folder path /etc/modprobe.d.

The file content is

```
options i915 enable_rc6 = 0
```

Anyone know for what this file is for. If I keep this file, my keyboard's Fn+ right and left arrow key is not working.

```
OS: Ubuntu 17.04
Environment: lightdm
Model: Acer Aspire E 15 E5-575G-50ZZ
```

If this is a bug, In launchpad, to which team/repository I should log query.

Comment: It passes an option to Intel's GPU driver i915. Here is more on rc6: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagementRC6

Comment: Assk the packaging system which package owns the file: `dpkg -S /etc/modprobe.d/i915_disable_rc6.conf`

Comment: @waltinator I am getting. "dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /etc/modprobe.d/i915_disable_rc6.conf".

Comment: @mikewhatever Thanks. Currently I don't have issues mentioned in the article. Further, it disabled some important fn+ right key and left key. So  I will remove that file.